# Modern 3.8+ answers file for Enterprise Puppet Master?

Tags: puppet-enterprise

I've looked around for awhile to track down a filled out answers file that would be for an Enterprise version master, I was only able to locate something for version 2.0~ though and am not certain what has changed since then (below) can someone show me a (generic) master answers file that I can use to set up my master?

```
q_puppet_cloud_install=n
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_auth_user_email=jd.daniel@mheducation.com
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_auth_password=puppet
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_auth_user=console
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_database_install=y
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_database_name=console
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_database_password=puppet
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_database_root_password=puppet
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_database_user=console
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_httpd_port=443
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_install=y
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_inventory_hostname=${HOSTNAME}
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_inventory_port=8140
q_puppet_enterpriseconsole_master_hostname=${HOSTNAME}
q_puppet_symlinks_install=y
q_puppetagent_server=puppet
q_puppetagent_certname=puppet
q_puppetagent_install=y
q_puppetmaster_certname=puppet
q_puppetmaster_dnsaltnames=puppet
q_puppetmaster_enterpriseconsole_hostname=${HOSTNAME}
q_puppetmaster_enterpriseconsole_port=443
q_puppetmaster_forward_facts=n
q_puppetmaster_install=y
q_enable_future_parser=y
q_fail_on_unsuccessful_master_lookup=n
q_vendor_packages_install=y
q_install=y
```

Comment: There are sample answers files (all in one, etc.) in the `answers` directory in the installer tarball. This is all [detailed in the docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/install_automated.html).

Comment: Thanks, ill use this as the answer +1 to you